# ImportError: cannot import name 'relu6'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, pip

I was trying to run a machine learning code based on Keras/TensorFlow. When running in `tensorflow` environment, I encounter the following error:

```
from keras_applications.mobilenet import relu6
ImportError: cannot import name 'relu6'
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: which version of Keras do you have?

Comment: I had 2.2.4. Now I downgraded to 2.1.6. Now I get another error: `ImportError: You need to first `import keras` in order to use `keras_applications`.`

Comment: I had the same error message when running `coremltools.converters.keras.convert` to convert a keras model to coreml. The error was resolved by downgrading to `2.1.6` via `pip install keras==2.1.6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [answer](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7431) from GitHub.

You need to use a `CustomObjectScope` to import `relu6`.

Answer (score 2):

MobileNet was moved to [keras-applications](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications)

For keras `2.2.4`:

```
from keras.layers import ReLU
from keras.layers import DepthwiseConv2D
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your relu6 like this:

```
relu6 = keras.layers.ReLU(max_value=6, name="ReLU6")
```