# ImportError: You need to first `import keras` in order to use `keras_applications`

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, python-import

I was trying to run a machine learning code using `Tensorflow/Keras` in Anaconda 3. I initially had a problem [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51756108/importerror-cannot-import-name-relu6), but I downgraded Keras to 2.1.6, and that error is resolved. Now I get the following error:

````
    raise ImportError('You need to first `import keras` '
ImportError: You need to first `import keras` in order to use `keras_applications`. For instance, you can do:

```
import keras
from keras_applications import vgg16
```

Or, preferably, this equivalent formulation:

```
from keras import applications
```
````

And here is my import list:

```
import glob, cv2, pickle, re
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from keras.models import load_model, Model
from keras_applications.mobilenet import relu6
from layers import SRU, Attention, ShuffleImages
import tensorflow as tf
```

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Pls forget about your previous question if it's not really relevant with your present issue, and post *here* the *exact code* producing the error you get *now*...

Comment: `from keras.applications import vgg16`?

Comment: @DJK or `from keras_applications.mobilenet import relu6`, as per OP's previous linked question - who knows??

Comment: I updated the question. I can not post the whole code due to confidentiality.

Comment: so, why don't you simply `import keras` before attempting any other imports from keras, like the recommendation accompanying the error says??

Comment: @desertnaut still the same error when I do this!

Answer (score 2):

This a problem related to the backend choosed for your keras. Try verify if the backend in the keras configuration file is the same installed in your enviromment. To do so:

```
nano ~/.keras/keras.json
```

The file should be similar to :

```
{
    "image_data_format": "channels_last",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "floatx": "float32",
    "backend": "tensorflow"
}
```

In this case, tensorflow must be installed correctly in your computer. If want to change the backend to another one ("theano", "tensorflow", or "cntk") just change in the keras.json file.

Comment: On the keras site (https://keras.io/backend/) informs that this path in windows should be %USERPROFILE%/.keras/keras.json

Comment: Yes, the JSON is similar.

Comment: Maybe that's a silly answer, but have you tried putting 'import keras' before importing the other packages that use keras? Maybe your backend is not being loaded because there is no keras import before them.